# Flex through Flash Builder 4; Connecting to a dynamic XML feed: "The response is not a valid XML or a JSON string"

Tags: xml, apache-flex, mxml

I am learning how to use Flex with Adobe Flash Builder 4 standalone. I am working my through the Adobe Flash Build 4 Bible by David Gassner. This has led me to create my own micro problems to try and solve.

I am trying to connect to a dynamix XML feed created by the following aspx page:
generate_xml.aspx

When I create the data connection through the Data/Service panel, I can pick between XML and HTTP. I figured because the generate_xml.aspx has to generate the XML file first, I should use the HTTP service as opposed to the XML. The HTTP service offers GET, which seems to be the kinda thing I want.

However, I am really struggling to do this. I keep getting:

"The response is not a valid XML or a JSON string"

The actual STATIC generated XML file that is created by this page works perfectly when I save it and manually connect with the XML service. Therefore I know my XML code is properly formatted and contains no other HTML of JavaScript.

I figure my problem occurs because the page itself is .aspx, but I cannot work out how to successfully ask Flex to request the output of this page, rather than the page itself.

Comment: What are you getting as a response? Have you put a breakpoint there and examined what is being returned?

Comment: The response is:
"The response is not a valid XML or a JSON string"

I resolved this issue by changing the way my dedicated server 'handles' the generated file. Basically Flex was seeing the asp.net page that creates the XML and not the generated XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the way my dedicated server 'handles' the generated file. Basically Flex was seeing the asp.net page that creates the XML and not the generated XML. By changing the handler on the iis configuration on my dedicated server, I could trick Flex into parsing it purely as an XML file.